# Why might Page routing work on localhost, but break for some pages on production Azure server?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, razor-pages

I am publishing a new web app built with .Net core and Razor pages in VS. When testing locally, all pages/links work properly. When published to the Azure hosting server, the routing to some pages breaks and does not work (returns 404).

e.g

/Management/Programs - works on both localhost and live server
/Management/Programs/1 - works on localhost, but 404 on live

/Management/Programs on the file system goes to /Areas/Management/Pages/Programs/Index.cshtml
/Management/Programs/1 goes to /Areas/Management/Pages/Programs/View.cshtml

View.cshtml first line is:

```
@page "/Management/Programs/{id}"
```

Which should allow the project to parse and route the URL properly, but fails on production servers.

Also, the following code generates a two different URL patterns

```
<li class="no-sub-menu" is-active-route asp-path-pattern-root="/Management/Programs" asp-path-pattern-index="/Management/Programs/Index">
  <a asp-area="Management" asp-page="/Programs/Index">
    <span>Programs</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="no-sub-menu">
  <a class="teal" asp-area="Management" asp-page="/Programs/New">
    <span>New Program</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

The Programs link URL is "/Management/Programs", but the New Program link (one of the pages that routes break with) generates a link of:

"/?area=Management&page=%2FPrograms%2FNew"

We have looked at different code examples and server configurations, and are at a loss as to why it is not working only on the server environment. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm not sure if this can help track down the issue, but it seems to only happen to pages within an area that don't point to the folder's Index.cshtml

Comment: could you please share the code base in public repo, will try to reproduce  the issue.

Comment: Your Razor Pages should be located in a _Pages_ folders within each area e.g.  /Areas/Management/Pages/Programs/Index.cshtml. Although personally, I'd ditch areas in Razor Pages. Just a whole load of extra folders for little to no practical gain.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the code base in a public repo.

@MikeBrind You're right, I mis-typed the path, they are under Pages already

Comment: @Steve If your issue has been resolved, please add the answer to the answer part. Then this issue can be closed. Thank you.